# Django static JS File not loading

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static

When i am clicking button , js file is not loading internally..the static tag is not working inside home.html ...

Its been a very long time since I had to use Django templates but I am having some trouble loading static js files.

nav.html

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="{%  static  'css/home.css'  %}">
    <script src='/crudapp/static/home.js'></script> 
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap w/ Parcel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css" integrity="sha384-7mQhpDl5nRA5nY9lr8F1st2NbIly/8WqhjTp+0oFxEA/QUuvlbF6M1KXezGBh3Nb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
      body{
        background-color: rgb(54, 60, 58);
      }
      #dd{
        color:blanchedalmond;
      }
      .table{
       background-color: white;
       width:500px;
       margin-left: 500px;
      }
     
      
      .card{
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-left:500px;
        width:500px;
      }
      .card-body{
        margin-left:100px;
      }
      .navbar-brand{
        color:rgb(79, 200, 237);
      }
    </style>
    <link>
    <script  src="/crudapp/static/home.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{%url 'index' %}">CRUD</a>
          
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{%url 'data' %}">DATA</a>
              </li>
             
              
              
            </ul>
            
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
    
   
  </body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/home.js' %}"></script> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
  
  <body>
   
    {%include 'nav.html'%} 
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
           <form action="" method="POST">
            
                
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                <button type="submit" id="btnn" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
            

           </form>
           
        </div>
    </div>
   
    
    
   
  </body>
</html>
```

settings file

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'static')
```

directory

```
-static
    -css
    -js
       -home.js
```

home.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnn').on('click',function(){
      id=$('#id_Emp_ser').val()
      console.log(id)
      const dict_val={id}
      const s=JSON.stringify(dict_val)
      $ajax({
        url:"/crudapp/views/data",
        type:"POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        data:s,
     });

    });
});
```

Please help anyone from this..

Comment: Static files engine is not used here `<script src='/crudapp/static/home.js'>` Also you import same file twice, also this url does not match folder structure. Also you have unclosed `<link>` tag which makes nav.html a little _invalid_ html. And when you include nav.html into home.html it is included with all the `<doctype>`, `<html>` and other tags inside `<body>` of home.html which brings more invalid elements to the final page html.

Comment: When you fix all of it please debug your solution and ensure what exactly is broken. "When I click button" - this description does not really point directly onto django static files. To check if static files are configured correctly grab static file url from rendered page and open it manually in a separate tab. If file contents are shown then static files are fine but js itself or markup are broken. And check browser console for error messages when testing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
STATICFILES_DIRS
```

Rather than STATIC_ROOT

Answer (score 0):

### -------- handle Static Files In django --------

```
# Steps:
    # 1 - Create (static) folder in Root Directory of Project
    # 2 - Paste Your Static Files Folder in (static) Folder (js,css,images...etc)
    # 3 - Now Do Setting in (setting.py)
           STATIC_URL = '/static/'

           import os
           STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
            # ---------- OR ------------------------
            # ---------- if Django version above  3.2 then ----------
           STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR /'static']



    # 4 - add {% load static %} tag on top of html page
    # 5 - Now use ({% static 'assets/image.jpg' %}) tag in HTML File for calling static files
    # 6 - Done
```